# Multiple request handling with node.js

Tags: node.js, connection

I want to make some type of relay server:

- send a request to the node server from some client like: http myServer:port/node1?command=foo&type=bar
- parse out the request.url: /node1?command=foo&type=bar
- send a GET to the second server with request.url attached and receive a JSON object from the server(request.url) according to the request : http someOtherServer/node1?command=foo&type=bar
- deliver the JSON object back to the client

Currently I have access to the url from the request, but as you may know that's not a hard task, since it's 'request.url'. 
Basically I want to call a heroku instance from an iPhone app, have the heroku instance relay the request to another server and send the response back to the iPhone app.

Comment: So what's your actual question?  If it's what libraries you should probably be using, I would say (Express.js)[http://expressjs.com/] and (Request)[https://github.com/mikeal/request]

Comment: The question is how can I accept a request, keep that first request on some kind of hold. Do a request to a second server, get the response and send that response as the response for the first request. I am already using express. I didn't know about request thow. Have to check it out.

Comment: Yeah, you're just thinking of the responses the wrong way.  The user's client makes the request to your server. It takes that and gets its pertinent information from that request.  Your server then makes an API call to another server.  (Your client's request is still waiting.)  Once you get the response from the other server, you'll take the response and send it back to your client using their initial request.

Comment: How would you do that in node. I wouldn't have a problem doing this in java but i really don't get it in node.

Comment: By using Express to handle routes, and request to send HTTP requests to another URL?  

Look, this is one of those things where you are going to have to learn on your own.  Not going to write your code for you.  

Check out https://runnable.com/express for some boilerplate Express code, and read the request docs.  It will guide you on making POST and GET requests properly using that library.

Comment: What part you don't get in node that you did in Java? The code to execute and libraries that you can use or how Node event model is different from Java threaded model?